# Has the rate of papers uploaded to arXiv changed due to Covid-19?

Tags: arxiv, productivity, covid-19

I'm wondering how much Covid-19 affected scientific productivity, if it affected productivity negatively at all (c.f. Newton actually did a lot of his most important work while the University of Cambridge was closed due to plague).

I'm using the rate at which papers are published on arXiv as a proxy for "scientific productivity", fully aware that it is not a perfect proxy and probably lags actual productivity by quite a bit. If country-specific statistics are available, e.g. "The number of publications by authors from Italy changed by __% on 9 March 2020, the date the lockdown started", that's even better.

Comment: Do you assume all researchers are at home or still at work? Can they / did they take material home? Is it possible for them to work effectively at home? Are you assuming they will get more work done at home? no students to distract them, based on your point about Newton...

Comment: @SolarMike are you assuming all these things about the question that aren't actually in it?

Comment: No I clearly asked if **you** were making those assumptions...

Comment: @SolarMike my interpretation is Allure is asking an empirical question that does not require assuming anything. It sounds like you’re trying to come up with a theoretical model to answer the question by pure reason/theoretical analysis, and want to know what assumptions you should make, but I don’t think that’s what’s being asked for.

Comment: I think too short time has passed to have some statistics. Speaking for myself, I had to put on hold at least one ongoing manuscript because I had to stop the experimental activity. For another manuscript, nothing has changed because the experimental results were already completed. For third manuscript, which I planned to start writing at the beginning of March, I  instead postponed the start at the beginning of April because I'm now too busy organizing the online lectures, and I'll probably submit it with fewer experimental results.

Comment: I downvoted this because the best answer can be found on ArXiv.org, not here.

Comment: @DanRomik I asked what assumptions were being made... I did not and still don't feel the need to ask the question that the OP asked.

Comment: Research takes time. This has been three months now, with much general disruption. Why do you think there would be any effect over such a period?

Comment: @Buffy are you assuming that I think there would have been an effect? I'm asking if there has been an effect. If there is no effect then that's an answer too, and if there is an effect it could be either way (i.e. more papers or fewer papers are both possible).

Comment: But the effect may just be chaotic. It is what I'd predict anyway. Start the research now and in a year or so you will have an answer. Perhaps. Or maybe [five years as Andy Putman](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/145598/75368) suggests.

Comment: @Buffy in that case the answer is there is no answer yet.

Comment: Correct. I don't think there is a _meaningful_ answer yet. But the same is true of many things at the moment. But I'm guessing this was just curiosity on your part, not a question leading to some action item.

Comment: @Buffy I gotta say, I find it annoying when people assume things in the question that aren't there. Plus, if I had asked this question intending to do something with the answer, I should also be able to tell what action if any to take.

Comment: Yes, and for the same reason I find the question annoying. I don't see this site as a place to satisfy our curiosity only. Hmmm. I'm wondering how many academics have cats v dogs? I prefer questions with some substance, actually.

Comment: @Buffy we should probably discuss that on the meta.

Comment: I'll watch for a question there.

Comment: @Buffy on reflection I am not keen to start a discussion on the meta. If you do, however, I will participate.

Comment: How on Earth is this opinion-based? It's asking for data, not an explanation of the data. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Three months on, it seems clear the answer is yes - but the submissions are increasing. June submissions outnumbered May submissions by almost 3000, and it's the largest ever recorded as well. Voting to reopen (again) so it can be added as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ArXiv posts its monthly submission statistics [here](https://arxiv.org/stats/monthly_submissions). It's noisy data even in the absence of viruses, so I can't tell if there's an effect yet or not. Then again, I'm no statistician. Extrapolating the March data as of today (March 19th), it's at least set to be larger than the February number of submissions, as is typical for March submissions.

However, even if the number of monthly arXiv submissions is to be considered a good proxy, it will likely lag by more time than we have seen so far. Yes, closures, adapting to online classes, and changed schedules will delay new experiments and other activities. However, finishing writing up manuscripts already in the pipeline, or analyzing already collected data are still productive tasks that will lead to new submissions for quite a while. Not to mention people such as myself, who can continue our theoretical/numerical work from home.

Comment: Rough estimation using arXiv statistics: 8938 articles in March (as of March, 22) so about 12,594 for the whole month. About the same as March 2019 (12,654). Of course, March submissions are the results of months of research, so it doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 9):

I think it will be interesting to study this 5 years from now, but right now is way too soon.  At least in math, people don’t post papers at a steady, constant rate.  I personally post around 3 papers per year, and most of those represent work that is at least a year old (often much longer than that) by the time I get around to writing it up.  Given what I’ve got partially written right now, I suspect that I will post about the same number (or even a little more) this year, bit that’s just part of the ebb and flow of research.  What is harder to predict is the effect of all this chaos on the production of new math, which won’t be visible for several years.

Comment: More than math, many experimental fields will be affected, all those in which labs have been shut down.

Comment: That’s absolutely the case.  I feel terrible for my colleagues who can’t event comfort themselves with their work in these dark days.

Answer (score 3):

I think your assumption that scientific productivity can be measured by arXiv uploads is flawed. Surely it can measure that the usual workflow has been changed - but especially for short periods of time, productivity cannot be measured by number of papers.

Taking myself as an example. I am using my time at home to do research tasks I have put off for too long. Cleaning up a large code base. Revisiting some old results. These are not tasks that results directly in arXiv uploads, but tasks which are needed in the long run. What I hear from my colleagues, is that they are doing similar things - if not completely worn down by teaching and supervising remotely, of course.