# COVID-19 and decrease in research productivity

Tags: productivity, covid-19

I wonder if there are any statistics or study analyzing the impact of isolation, teleworking due to COVID-19 pandemic on res.earchers' productivity.

From the beginning of the pandemic, I really feel that my productivity and enthusiasm in my research have decreased. I would like to avoid any opinion-based question but I would like to know if there are some recommendations to solve this issue

Comment: If every researcher's productivity has decreased, maybe we just have to wait a bit longer for the researchers who study productivity to become productive...

Comment: @astronat: It seems every week or so I'll reply to a comment (in one of the 4 main groups I participate in) something to the effect that I was thinking the same thing but "you" beat me to it. I wish I could say the same here, but I can't --- I didn't come anywhere near to thinking of your delicious observation!

Comment: @astronat haha! nice point indeed!

Comment: Well, for some it goes up, for some it goes down. Definitely it went up for Newton. Possibly even for Einstein in the 1st WW.

Comment: With less than a year of experience it is too early for any meaningful statistics.

Comment: @Buffy Particularly since such statistics will be self-selecting and suffer from survivor bias. But then, 70% of all statistics are anyway made up on the spot ;-)

Comment: Some statistics on productivity during the early part of the pandemic can be found e.g. [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3712813) and [here](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1365-2435.13734). The patterns may have changed since the studied data was collected.

Comment: Little change: https://arxiv.org/stats/monthly_submissions

Comment: Closely related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/145583/has-the-rate-of-papers-uploaded-to-arxiv-changed-due-to-covid-19

Comment: @CaptainEmacs you are wrong. I have a T-shirt that says 42.7% of all statistics are made up. So that proofs it. (I wear it during my intro Stats lectures)